# Swift : Some classes not de-initialised

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, deinit

In the following code `NSString` and `NSNumber`  are not de-initialised when the reference is removed . `NSMutableString` and `NSAttributedString` are de-initialised . What is the criteria for deinit ?

```
class WeakHolder<R : AnyObject> {
    weak var cheez : R?
    init(_ _cheez : R) {
        cheez = _cheez
    }
}
```

---

```
do {
        var nsStringCollection = [NSString(string: "77"),NSString(string: "99")]
        let weakNSStringHolder = WeakHolder(nsStringCollection[1])
        nsStringCollection.removeLast()
        print("NSString : \(weakNSStringHolder.cheez)")
    }

    do {
        var nsMutableStringCollection = [NSMutableString(string: "77_m"),NSMutableString(string: "99_m")]
        let weakNSMutableStringHolder = WeakHolder(nsMutableStringCollection[1])
        nsMutableStringCollection.removeLast()
        print("NSMutableString : \(weakNSMutableStringHolder.cheez)")
    }

    do {
        var nsNumberCollection = [NSNumber(integerLiteral: 77),NSNumber(integerLiteral: 99)]
        let weakNumberHolder = WeakHolder(nsNumberCollection[1])
        nsNumberCollection.removeLast()
        print("Number : \(weakNumberHolder.cheez)")
    }

    do {
        var nsAttributedCollection = [NSAttributedString(string: "77_atts"),NSAttributedString(string: "99_atts")]
        let weakAttributedHolder = WeakHolder(nsAttributedCollection[1])
        nsAttributedCollection.removeLast()
        print("AttrString : \(weakAttributedHolder.cheez)")
    }
```

---

Output :

```
NSString : Optional(99)
NSMutableString : nil
Number : Optional(99)
AttrString : nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short `NSString` objects are stored directly in their (tagged) pointer, and do not require memory management. Other static strings are stored in the binary and may never be deallocated. Neither allocate memory, so neither must release it.

`NSMutableString` and `NSAttributedString` allocate actual objects, so they also need to deallocate them.

Both behaviors are implementation details and you should not rely on them. They are not promised.

The rule for memory management is to hold a strong reference to anything you care about, and remove your strong reference when you no longer care about it. `deinit` should only cleanup memory (calling `free` on malloc-blocks, for example, if needed). No "business logic" should be in a `deinit`; there's no promise it will ever run. (For example, during normal program termination, `deinit` is skipped, unlike in C++.)